# Проблеммы с подключением Rxjava 2 на Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, rxjava2

Я прописываю в grad:

```
classpath 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
```

Андройд студио что то подключает, закачивает, пишет успешно. После Я пытаюсь применить простой

```
Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.just("Hello, world!");
```

в активити. И вот тут начинаются проблемы.

Андройд студио пытается подключить какой то левый, через комбинацию Alt+Enter :

```
import android.database.Observable;
```

После чего ругается на just... 
Я не понимаю как с этим работать.

На любые попытки вручную прописать import из примеров, посвященных этой либе(не относящиеся к той строчки кода ),ругается и пишет что такое не существует. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Куда вы подключаете? Что тут сложного:

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.x.y"
```

Это нужно подключить в `build.gradle` в папке `app` в `dependencies {...}`

[Тут всё есть](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: ВОУ! Это работает. Спасибо) Я новичок в этой андроид студии) Правда там не было написано конкретно где)

Comment: Гуглите, там всё есть. Самое сложное это научиться задавать правильные вопросы, но здесь же вы его смогли задать... P.S. Если ответ вам подошел, поставьте как принятый (нажмите на галочку). P.S.S. Ну это и у меня изначально вызывало проблемы, когда возникают схожие вопросы загляните сюда:http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/gradle.php. А сейчас для начала прочтите про: dependencies {...}

Comment: Система 5 минут не давала кликнуть по галке) Правда Я пытался)))